# Google Chrome layout differs

Tags: css, google-chrome, layout

I have a web page which has always looked nice before in Chrome.
Now I have the situation that the layout is different on different systems.
I've tried to find any differences in configuration, but I cannot find anything.
The version, the extensions, the Windows version, are all the same.

I know the fix is easy (edit the textfield width), but does anybody know what could be the cause of this inconsistency?

**Here is the layout on my colleague's system:**
[image: Correct layout]

**And here is the layout on my system:**
[image: Wrong layout]

Comment: `inspect` the layout from your system and your friends system using `developer tools` and check the `width`

Comment: I already checked and the width differed indeed, however my question was WHY does it differ? The settings are all the same.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of non-standard CSS uses and may be both your system have different screen resolutions. You can preserver same look everywhere using standard rules of CSS.

Comment: How can different screen resolutions result in different layouts if you use standard CSS? I'm using the standards.

Comment: Standard means do not use any deprecated rue, use media query, avoid fix width in px size.

Suppose your colleague have monitor of 1600x900 and you have 1366x768 and you have specified  sizes like 900px + 500px for two divisions. It will work pretty good for big monitor but it will create chaos in small monitor.

Comment: Ok thanks for that. So let's say it is the resolution which is messing things up. Why does it matter now all of the sudden? It worked before.. Could it be an Chrome update or something?

Answer (score -1):

If it's problem of size of text field then use this :

`<input type="text" name="name" size="35" value="">`

`size=35` is specifies the width of an `<input>` element, in characters. Default value is 20([w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_size.asp))

Or view more in w3.org [(input.text.attrs.size)](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.text.html#input.text.attrs.size)

Comment: I already have the solution to the problem. The question however, was WHY the width differs on two machines?